# Outlook takes a long time to open new meeting request

Tags: microsoft-outlook, webex

When Outlook is open, and I click New Items drop-down, and then select meeting, it takes over a minute to open the window.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling and re-installing Cysco WebEx Meetings solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! The future appreciates this effort.